# Same price on multiple values on CSVI custom fields import

Tags: virtuemart

Using Custom Fields For All and have problem with importing of it with CSVI.

I have the product with several sizes.
Each of sizes have increase in price.

For example.

S - 100$
M - 102$
L - 106$

My import file:

```
product_name,product_category,product_price,custom_param,virtuemart_product_id,custom_price,published,custom_title,custom_value,product_sku
T-shirt, Clothes, 100, S~M~L, 15, 0~102~106, 1, Size~Size~Size, customfieldsforall~customfieldsforall~customfieldsforall, tshirt, Y~Y~Y
```

On Product Page after import we can see Sizes that displayed properly, but we have the same price on each Size (102$):
[image]

If we go to Admin Panel > Product (T-Shirt)>Custom Fields we can see that displayed only one value:[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].